# ¿Cómo conectar SQL Server a Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql-server, wordpress

tengo una ERP en una base de datos SQL Server, y tengo una web elaborada en wordpress que fue convertida en una intranet con el plugin "All-in-One Intranet".

Lo que queremos hacer es que un grupo de usuarios de la base de datos del ERP (SQL Server) puedan acceder a la intranet con sus mismos datos de acceso.

**Me explico mejor:** No queremos que los usuarios estén en la base de datos de wordpress sino que estén en la base de datos de nuestro ERP, entonces necesito que con esos mismos accesos puedan acceder a la intranet, por ende si un usuario es eliminado de la ERP también pierde el acceso de la intranet.

El tema seria como hacerlo?

Como podría hacer una conexión con mi wordpress ya elaborado en su base de datos predeterminada (MySQL) a SQL Server, y dar acceso a los usuarios de esa base de datos.

---

Gracias por la repuesta estimado.

Lo que pasa es que el objetivo es dejar que el ERP sea la plataforma que permita controlar que usuarios están habilitados.

Piénsalo de la siguiente forma... Inicialmente solo necesito 3 campos: login (email), password y saber si el usuario esta habilitado.

Esa info la tiene el ERP, pero dentro de las facultades existen diversos sistemas de control de usuarios y todos están esparcidos...

Por ejemplo sería ideal que cuando un usuario se desvincule de la empresa, se le bloquee su email o se le eliminen sus accesos a puertas o huellas.

Ahí es donde toma sentido que el ERP le avise a otros sistemas del cambio de estado de un usuario. Pero ese cambio debe ser casi inmediato, no trabajar con Cron (registros recurrentes de horario) o algún método similar.

Imagina que despiden a alguien en la mañana.. si los sistemas están disgregados y sin comunicación.. todo habría que hacerlo a mano: Quitarle el acceso a puertas, bloquear su email, avisar a otras áreas.. todo eso puede tomar días!

Por eso.. si hacemos un cron serviría.. si, pero únicamente cuando el registro se haya actualizado.

Ejemplo: un usuario entra en la mañana al ERP y cambia su password. Si tienes los cron corriendo en las noches, la contraseña no se actualizaría en el WordPress si no hasta el otro día.. lo que lo hace poco práctico.

Por eso que es preferible armar una estructura donde la información se actualice con segundos de diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que la mejor solución es a la inversa de la que tu propones.

Puedes poner en el SQL Server un nuevo servidor vinculado que vincule el MySQL de WordPress.

A partir de aquí, crear un procedimiento almacenado (en SQL Server) que sincronice las cuentas del SQL Server con el de WordPress en la base de datos MySQL. Luego creas un `job` en el SQL Server para que ejecute el procedimiento con la periodicidad que quieras.

Otro asunto es saber como están almacenadas las contraseñas, probablemente con encriptaciones distintas, por lo que ahí deberéis investigar.

Otra solución es pasar todo el contenido del MySQL a una base de datos de SQL Server ([aquí tienes documentación](https://ayudawp.com/instalar-wordpress-en-microsoft-sql-server/)), pero sería otra base de datos distinta a la del ERP (en el mismo servidor) y aplicaría igualmente la solución anterior.